# Audio synthesis in Haskell using reactive-banana

Tags: haskell, audio, midi, reactive-banana

I'm trying to get started with reactive-banana and want to create a simple synthesizer. There are lots of GUI examples, but I have trouble applying them to audio. Since audio APIs have callbacks that say "give me n samples of audio" I figure I should fire an event each callback (using the snd part of what newAddHandler returns) that contains the number of samples to generate, a pointer where they should be written, and timing info to coordinate MIDI events. The IO action passed to reactimate would then write the samples to the pointer. MIDI events would be similarly fired from another callback and also contain timing info.

This is where I get stuck however. I guess the audio signal is supposed to be a behaviour, but how do I "run" a behaviour for the right amount of time to obtain the samples? The right amount of course depends on MIDI events that might occur between two audio callbacks.

Comment: it's not reactive-banana, but still might be interesting: notes on timing in http://hackage.haskell.org/package/live-sequencer-0.0.4/src/src/Event.hs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To approach problems like this, I find useful to take a *semantic viewpoint*: What is an audio signal? What type can I use to represent it?

Essentially, an audio signal is a time-varying amplitude

```
Audio = Time -> Double
```

which suggests the representation as a behavior

```
type Audio = Behavior Double
```

Then, we can use the `<@>` combinator to query the amplitude at a particular moment in time, namely whenever an event happens.

However, for reasons of efficiency, audio data is generally stored in *blocks* of 64 bytes (or 128, 256). After all, processing needs to be fast and it's important to use tight inner loops. This suggests to model audio data as a behavior

```
type Audio = Behavior (Vector Double)
```

whose values are 64 byte blocks of audio data and which changes whenever the time period corresponding to 64 bytes is over.

Connecting to other APIs is done only after the semantic model has been clarified. In this case, it seems a good idea to write the audio data from the behavior into a buffer, whose contents is then presented whenever the external API calls your callback.

---

By the way, I don't know whether reactive-banana-0.8 is fast enough yet to be useful for sample-level audio processing. It shouldn't be too bad, but you may have to choose a rather large block size.

Comment: Disregarding performance and assuming Behaviour Double, what you and John L say is that a clock mechanism fires an event for each sample (e.g. 44100 times per second)?

Comment: Having a clock event that fires every X times per second is a good way to build `Behavior`s that change every X times per second, indeed.

Comment: Great! I'm starting to see how the pieces fit together, but there still seems to be something vital I'm missing. How do I make the clock event? Looking at the available functions the closest I get is using replicate to get a [()] that I can spill, apply, collect, and finally fmap on the "generate n samples" event, but I guess all the events in one buffer will share the same timestamp, i.e. the measured time when the "generate n samples" event occurs, instead of t/sampleRate where t = [0..].

Comment: You need to import an external clock mechanism. Most UI programming frameworks like SDL, wxWidgets etc. provide timer objects. (You can also roll your one by using `forkIO` and `threadDelay`.) Use `fromAddHandler` to convert it to an `Event`.

Comment: If memory serves me right SDL's timer has millisecond precission, meaning that if it was precise there would be an event every 44.1 samples. Even if it was precise and stable enough, it could only be used for generating audio real-time. What if I want to use the same synthesizer code (FRP network) to write an audio file at above (or more likely below) real-time speed? In case we are not on the same page, I would like to use FRP for the synth's internal event system (e.g. "attack segment of envelope has finished, go to decay segment", or "note was released, move to release segment").

Comment: Yup. The point is that `reactive-banana` doesn't provide a default timer implementation because different use cases require different precisions etc. You have to create a timer yourself, which means to create a `Event Time` via a `fromAddHandler`. This can be faster than real time, even, nothing stops from implementing a "clock" that counts logical time, but fires as fast as it can.

Comment: Ahh, there's no actual timestamp. :) Have I got this right: In the audio callback I could `replicateM bufsize (fireclock param)` or similar and reactimate writes to the buffer (info included in param), and the synth calculations are all events, not behaviours (e.g. accumE for an oscillator's phase accumulator).

Answer (score 2):

Presuming the intention is to do something live, I think firing an event for each callback is going to be extremely limiting.  Most audio APIs expect that these callbacks will return very quickly (e.g. typically you would never call malloc or do blocking IO in one).  Firing an FRP event may work for very simple processing, but I think if you try to do anything more complex you'll get dropouts in the audio stream.

I would expect a more viable approach is to fire events yourself (by a clock, or in response to GUI events, etc) and generate a buffer of audio, and have the callback API read from that buffer.  I know that some audio APIs (e.g. portaudio) have a buffered mode which handles some of this automatically.  Although if all you have is a callback API, it's not too hard to add a buffer on top of that.

Comment: Thanks, probably the event fired in the callback should mean "fill the next buffer" instead of the current buffer, and then the buffer filled by the previous callback can be handed off to the API to avoid stalling (firing events in response to a system clock will likely result in drift and eventually drop-outs). Regardless of where the event is fired the biggest problem is the reactive-banana part described in the second paragraph of my question.

Comment: @absence I suspect you will want to have a type like `Behavior Builder` (using e.g. Builder from the latest `bytestring`).  You can accumulate events to create that Behavior, with audio inputs adding to it and the output callback flushing it.

Comment: Will using Builder let me use reactive-banana to calculate the samples though? I want to have behaviours for envelopes, oscillators, filters, etc. (they're all basically Time -> Double) and I still don't understand how make samples out of it.

Comment: You need a clock to drive the network (i.e. something of type `Event Time`).  You set the sampling rate (e.g. 44100), and from that you can calculate the time between samples, which is how often your clock event needs to fire (schedule this with a yield loop or similar).  Then use `oscil <@> clockE` to get output.  One complication is that for real-time audio, you won't be able to do very much processing if your clock runs at each sample.  Typically each clock event would trigger  a block of audio data, 64 or 128 samples, so `Behavior (Time -> Vector Double)`.